# Can I get latitude and longitude for multiple addresses at a time with leaflet js?

Tags: leaflet

Can I get latitude and longitude for multiple addresses at a time with leaflet js as a JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @IvanSanchez said, Leaflet wasn't made to do that.  There is, however, a great geocoding plugin to Leaflet that is available on github:
https://github.com/smeijer/L.GeoSearch

Answer (score 1):

No.

LeafletJS is a map display library, not a [geocoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding) service.